# jdoc include work just in index.php

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I'm working on the costume Joomla template and I'm overriding the footer I have a menu (footer_menu) when I sit

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer_menu" style="html5" />
```

in the index .php the menu appears, but when in, set it in my custom footer it not work

my footer.php :

```
<?php    
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>

<footer class="container shadow p-3 mb-2 bg-white rounded">

<div class="row mt-1">
        <div class="col">
                <!-- Menu Footer -->
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer_menu" style="html5" /> 

        </div>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;


/** @var JDocumentHtml $this */

$app  = JFactory::getApplication();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();






// Output as HTML5
$this->setHtml5(true);
// Detecting Active Variables
$option   = $app->input->getCmd('option', '');
$view     = $app->input->getCmd('view', '');
$layout   = $app->input->getCmd('layout', '');
$task     = $app->input->getCmd('task', '');
$itemid   = $app->input->getCmd('Itemid', '');
$sitename = htmlspecialchars($app->get('sitename'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

if ($task === 'edit' || $layout === 'form')
{
    $fullWidth = 1;
}
else
{
    $fullWidth = 0;
}


// Add template js
JHtml::_('script', 'template.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));

// Add html5 shiv
JHtml::_('script', 'jui/html5.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true, 'conditional' => 'lt IE 9'));

// Add Stylesheets
JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'template.css', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Agma Theme</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <header class="container shadow p-3 mb-2 bg-white rounded mt-3 " role="banner">
                <div class="row">   

                                    <nav class="nav">
                                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="html5" /> 
                                     </nav>
                                 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="html5" /> 
                </div>             

        </header>

        <div>

        </div>


        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="html5" /> 



    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: How are you loading footer.php in index.php? Do you have any modules assigned to `footer_menu` position?

Comment: yes using the same jdoc:include :

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code from `index.php`.

Comment: It is because you are giving the name of the menu in place of module position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jdoc:include` to include `footer.php` won't work. It's used to create module positions. So this code creates a module position called `footer`:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="html5" />
```

You can now assign modules to `footer` position. Note that `footer.php` is not loaded in this case. And it's not really needed unless you want to split your template into several files for organizing, reusability, etc.

So what you can do is keep it that way, just wrap it with code from `footer.php` for styling:

```
<footer class="container shadow p-3 mb-2 bg-white rounded">
<div class="row mt-1">
        <div class="col">
                <!-- Menu Footer -->
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="html5" /> 

        </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

You can, of course, change the name of position to `footer_menu` or anything else.

But if you need to include PHP files inside `index.php`, use native `include` or `require`, e.g.:

```
include __DIR__ . '/footer.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access jdoc:include in any place, you can include modules with PHP:

```
<?php 
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $doc->loadRenderer( 'modules' );
echo $renderer->render( 'footer', ['style' => 'html5'], null );
?>
```